# Como extraer Códigos Postales de Google My Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación y tengo algunos problemas con las zonas de entrega, en google my maps tengo algunas Geocercas ya trazadas pero no se si exista la posibilidad de que de esas mismas Geocercas pueda extraer los Códigos postales que esta abarcando.

o exista la posibilidad de extraer Códigos postales de Google Maps por algún otro metodo.

Gracias po sus aportes

Answer (score 0):

Puedes extraerlos directamente con la API de google places, te adjunto un pequeño ejemplo que extrae direccion, codigo postal, pais, estado y la calle:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="locationField">
      <input
        id="autocomplete"
        placeholder="Enter your address"
        onFocus="geolocate()"
        type="text"
      />
    </div>

    <!-- Note: The address components in this sample are typical. You might need to adjust them for
               the locations relevant to your app. For more information, see
         https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
    -->

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField">
          <input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true" />
        </td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2">
          <input class="field" id="route" disabled="true" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
          <input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField">
          <input
            class="field"
            id="administrative_area_level_1"
            disabled="true"
          />
        </td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField">
          <input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
          <input class="field" id="country" disabled="true" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=TU_API_KEY&callback=initAutocomplete&libraries=places&v=weekly"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

y el index.js:

```
let placeSearch;
let autocomplete;
const componentForm = {
  street_number: "short_name",
  route: "long_name",
  locality: "long_name",
  administrative_area_level_1: "short_name",
  country: "long_name",
  postal_code: "short_name",
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
    { types: ["geocode"] }
  );
  autocomplete.setFields(["address_component"]);
  autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (const component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = "";
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  for (const component of place.address_components) {
    const addressType = component.types[0];

    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      const val = component[componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      const geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
      };
      const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy,
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

Desde google cloud tendras que activar la api de google maps y google places, una vez hecho, en el script del html tendrás que ponerla donde pone TU_API_KEY

Este es el ejemplo básico que da google.

Tienes toda la documentación en: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform#maps_places_autocomplete_addressform-javascript

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Gracias Ivan, me ayuda un poco a la solución de mi problema

Comment: Si solamente quieres el código postal, puedes dejar solamente el input id="postal_code" y ahi lo tendrás!